# How to have text delete itself in prompt window in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I want to put a command inbetween two echo strings so that when the other appears, it is on the top row and the first echo text dissapears.

Something like this:

```
echo Stuff that gets deleted when the second print comes
choice /C X /T 3 /D X > nul
deletepreviousecho
echo New Words.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cls:

```
echo Stuff that gets deleted when the second print comes
pause
cls
echo New Words.
```

Oh and pause prints out "Press any key to continue . . ." if you don't want that use:

```
pause>nul
```

Comment: @user2774738: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you found this answer helpful, you can upvote it and/or check it as the correct answer to your question.